# want to make a thumbnail image with a block button on it and it should be responsive, both the image and button on it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[I WANT IT TO BE LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or3Qf.png)

```html
http://www.patient-experience.org/Images/Stock-Art/For-Patients.aspx
```

I want to make a responsive thumbnail image with a button on it , and the button should take the size of the image inside the thumbnail .
I am using bootstrap 3 , and using these classes for the above above div.
img-responsive, img-thumbnail, btn , btn-block . !!
can someone please help me ?

```html
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="col-md-12"> <img src="http://www.patient-experience.org/Images/Stock-Art/For-Patients.aspx" class="img-thumbnail"> 
<button class="btn btn-block">submit</button></div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please make sure you [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to improve your question. It will make it easier for others to understand it and help you out.

Comment: @ThiagoSá thank you buddy , yeah i am new and really dont have much idea about it ...

Comment: <div class="col-md-12">
  <img src="images/..." class="img-thumbnail">
    <button class="btn btn-block">submit</button> 
</div>

@Shaggy 
thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code, including any relevant CSS.

Comment: @Shaggy will it work right now ? and by the way im using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
https://jsfiddle.net/59m0nyfq/1/

```
 <img src="http://www.patient-experience.org/Images/Stock-Art/For-Patients.aspx" class="img-responsive">


<button class="btn btn-block" style="display: inline-block; 
position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; 
width: 100%; height: 20%; opacity: 0.5; background-color:red; color:#fff;">submit</button>
```

Comment: If you think this answer is helpful, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with positioning. You need to wrap them with a `div` and add the `img-thumbnail` to that div too.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="img-thumbnail" style="position: relative;">
        <img src="http://www.patient-experience.org/Images/Stock-Art/For-Patients.aspx" class="img-thumbnail"> 
        <button class="btn btn-block" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the button will overlap your image, so you should add opacity for it.

Here is a working **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q5fs170a/)**.

Comment: but then there will be two thumbnails and what i am working on is having 4 cols, i mean there are 4 (col-md-3) and for me the button is taking the full width of the col-md-3 class

Comment: nope, there is one thumbnail. the `div` need it to apply css rules. and you sad: _and the button should take the size of the image inside the thumbnail_ . you can repeat it anytime, anywhere.

Comment: but when i resize it , it changes.. i have uploaded a picture of the design i want it to be .. can you please see that and help me with it , thanks in advance

Comment: I posted an answer with what it should look like based on your picture.

Comment: @RachelS Thanks , but the width is fix respect to the col , when you try to resize it , the button width is not constantly decreasin respect to the img .

Comment: Oh you have to make the image responsive. I updated my post and fiddle